# Using @Select for query data, but got 'Invalid bound statement (not found)'

Tags: java, spring, junit, mybatis, ibatis

I have a project using spring+mybatis. I want to using @Select for querying data, but got error log like "Invalid bound statement (not found)".

I find a article in mybatis's Chinese official website, it said i can use @Select query data, just like the way using mapper.xml.

Can anybody help me?

I searched many answer in google, people always said their xml or mapper configured in wrong way, but I don't have mapper files, either .xml or .java, so i don't know what i did wrong.

```
@Select("SELECT * FROM store_order WHERE id>#{lastId} AND order_add_status=#{status} ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT #{limit}")
List<StoreOrderData> queryStoreOrderDataListByStatus(@Param("status") int status, @Param("lastId") long lastId, @Param("limit") int limit);
```

i hope somebody can tell me which step i did wrong? Could it happen due to database's configuration?

there is error log:

```
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): com.heshengbang.middleware.biz.store.dao.StoreOrderDao.queryStoreOrderDataListByStatus
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod$SqlCommand.<init>(MapperMethod.java:189)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.<init>(MapperMethod.java:43)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.cachedMapperMethod(MapperProxy.java:58)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:51)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.queryStoreOrderDataListByStatus(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you add the entire log?

Comment: @JonathanJohx i have add the entire log in main content.

Comment: I posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add `@Results` to customize mapping of column names to POJO properties in the result of your query. It needs to be placed on the same method as the `@Select`

Example:

```
@Results({
    @Result(property = "id", column = "id"),
    @Result(property = "status", column = "order_add_status")
})
```

Comment: This is a new knowledge for me, i haven't use @Results annotation. i have tried but it didn't work. But i'm much sure it may help other people, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This error message:

> org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement
>   (not found):

This is caused by a wrong syntax of the query written on `queryStoreOrderDataListByStatus` methodm the error is `id>#{lastId}` change **=** instead of **>** and this should work.

```
@Select("SELECT * FROM store_order WHERE id>#{lastId} AND order_add_status=#{status} ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT #{limit}")
List<StoreOrderData> queryStoreOrderDataListByStatus(@Param("status") int status, @Param("lastId") long lastId, @Param("limit") int limit);
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, you provide a new solution, i have tried but it didn't work. But i'm much sure it may help other people.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem a few days ago, it happened because there have two overload function in java files, which both named 'queryStoreOrderDataListByStatus', it will cause mybatis can't found the right one, so the problem is contingent.

I think this is a bug of mybatis, it can avoid this problem by matching parameter list.

Comment: It is a known limitation (overloaded methods are not supported, ATM). There is a [feature request](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/1482) and a [proposed fix](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/pull/1519). Feedback is welcome. :)